# Zurb Foundation 4 How to maintain columns when printing

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 4.2.3 from Zurb, but when I print pages, the grid layout is always not maintained.

For example,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 columns">
        XXX
    </div>
    <div class="small-9 columns">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    </div>
</div>
```

This renders as 
[image]

but it becomes this when printed.

[image]

Is there a fix to this so that the grid layout is maintained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this to my .scss file at the end:

```
@media print {
  div.columns {
    float:left!important;
    padding-left:0.9375em!important;
    padding-right:0.9375em!important;
    width:8.3333333333%!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't quite work. The right column gets squeezed into a very small column. I've already tried something like this, but I couldn't find the best solution yet. Where did you get the `width: 8.333...%` from?

Comment: Oh right, for my example I was using a large-1 column grid.

I inspected the element with firebug and got the width there.

I guess for yours just inspect your columns and set your widths like that.

If you are using scss you can find an option "enable print styles" in the settings scss and turn that off.

Answer (score 1):

The issue ist that "*.large-XXX .columns*" in the grid is only defined for "*@media screen*":

foundation/_variables.scss:98

```
$small: "only screen and (min-width: #{$small-screen})";
```

foundation/components/_grid.scss:153

```
  @media #{$small} {

    @for $i from 1 through $total-columns {
      .large#{-$i} { @include grid-column($columns:$i,$collapse:null,$float:false); }
    }
    ...
  }
```

So what I did was add a line after foundation/_variables.scss is included that overrides this:

```
// This includes all of the foundation global elements that are needed to work with any of the other files.
@import "foundation/variables";

$small: "screen and (min-width: #{$small-screen}), print";
```

Of course, this only works if you don't auto-include all of foundation by way of *@import "foundation"*, but instead include all of them manually (i.e., uncomment the respective lines in _foundation.scss).

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the `variables.scss` file for Foundation 5, although it's not perfect.

```
// $screen: "only screen";
 $screen: "print, screen";
```